# Compare and remove elements out of dataframe columns of inconsistent arrays in Spark / PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, higher-order-functions

I'm new to Spark and I can't find a solution for my problem, any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

I have a Pyspark.sql.dataframe with two array columns which have Strings in it. Both column arrays have inconsistent lengths and some rows also have Null entries. I need to compare these two columns and have to delete for each row in column B an element of the array, when it is found in that row in the array in column OVERRIDE.

```
+---------------+---------------+
|    OVERRIDE   |         B     |
+---------------+---------------+
|          ['a']|      ['a','b']|
|           null|          ['b']|
|           null|      ['a','c']|
|      ['d','g']|      ['d','g']|
|           null|           null|
|          ['f']|          ['f']|
+---------------+---------------+
```

should look like this in the end:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|    OVERRIDE   |         B     |
+---------------+---------------+
|          ['a']|          ['b']|
|           null|          ['b']|
|           null|      ['a','c']|
|      ['d','g']|           null|
|           null|           null|
|          ['f']|           null|
+---------------+---------------+
```

I tried with

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_remove, array_intersect

df = df.withColumn('B', array_remove(df.B, df.OVERRIDE))
```

and also

```
df = df.withColumn('B', array_remove(df.B, array_intersect(df.OVERRIDE, df.B)))
```

but learnt that array_remove() can not iterate over the column, instead is just able to take one element (e.g. 'a') to delete it then in all rows of column B.

Do I have to build a udf function and if so how should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this using `udf`

```
@udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def removeFromRight(override,b):
if(override==None or b==None):
    return b

filtered_list=[x for x in b if x not in override]
if(len(filtered_list)==0):
    filtered_list=None
return filtered_list

test1=test.withColumn("new_overridden_col",removeFromRight(col("override"),col("b")))    
test1.show()

//output of test1
+--------+------+------------------+
|override|     b|new_overridden_col|
+--------+------+------------------+
|     [a]|[a, b]|               [b]|
|    null|   [b]|               [b]|
|    null|[a, c]|            [a, c]|
|  [d, g]|  null|              null|
|    null|  null|              null|
|     [f]|  null|              null|
+--------+------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Strangely enough, before your addition of row 3 and 4 it worked on a small sample set but not on the full dataset. Everytime I wanted to access/show or calculate with the new column "new_overridden_col" I got a pile of errors, but only then.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Spark >= 2.4.0 you can use the build-in [array_except(a, b)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_except). The function will return all the items that are present in a but not in b. Although the function works only when both params have not null values, therefore before using it we need to replace **null with empty array**.

Here is the python version:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_except, when, array, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [["a"], ["a", "b"]],
 [None, ["b"]],
 [None, ["a", "c"]],
 [["d", "g"], ["d", "g"]],
 [["f"], ["f"]]
], ["OVERRIDE", "B"])

df.withColumn("OVERRIDE", when(col("OVERRIDE").isNull(), array()).otherwise(col("OVERRIDE"))) \
  .withColumn("diff", array_except(col("B"), col("OVERRIDE"))) \
  .show()

// +--------+------+------+
// |OVERRIDE|     B|  diff|
// +--------+------+------+
// |     [a]|[a, b]|   [b]|
// |      []|   [b]|   [b]|
// |      []|[a, c]|[a, c]|
// |  [d, g]|[d, g]|    []|
// |     [f]|   [f]|    []|
// +--------+------+------+
```

And the Scala one:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_except, when, array}

val df = Seq(
 (Seq("a"), Seq("a", "b")),
 (null, Seq("b")),
 (null, Seq("a", "c")),
 (Seq("d", "g"), Seq("d", "g")),
 (Seq("f"), Seq("f"))
).toDF("OVERRIDE", "B")

df.withColumn("OVERRIDE", when($"OVERRIDE".isNull, array()).otherwise($"OVERRIDE"))
  .withColumn("diff", array_except($"B", $"OVERRIDE"))
  .show

// +--------+------+------+
// |OVERRIDE|     B|  diff|
// +--------+------+------+
// |     [a]|[a, b]|   [b]|
// |      []|   [b]|   [b]|
// |      []|[a, c]|[a, c]|
// |  [d, g]|[d, g]|    []|
// |     [f]|   [f]|    []|
// +--------+------+------+
```